# Scaling by transform does not work in UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, transform, scale

In the following program, no matter what value I put in the argument of CGAffineTransform(scaleX:y:), I get the same drawing result.

Why is that?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = .gray
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let scalingView = ScalingView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.view.addSubview(scalingView)
  }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class ScalingView: UIView {
  let subview: UIView!
  
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    subview = UIView()
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(subview)
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    subview.backgroundColor = .white
    let subviewSize = 100
    subview.frame.size = CGSize(width: subviewSize, height: subviewSize)
    subview.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY)
    subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
  }
}
```

---

```
subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
```

[scaleX: 1, y: 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9CeH.png)

---

```
subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
```

[scaleX: 2, y: 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ceNf.png)

---

```
subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```

[scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JtWV.png)

---

https://github.com/ll3Ynxnj/Sample-Swift-ViewScaling.git

Comment: This is not an answer but never never never implement  `layoutSubviews` without calling `super`. You will utterly break layout if you do that.

Comment: Also call `super` in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `viewWillAppear` can be called more than once so you shouldn't blindly create and add a new subview there since you might end up adding more and more subviews. You should likely add the subview in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @matt Fixed. Thanks for pointing this out. [GitHub](https://github.com/ll3Ynxnj/Sample-Swift-ViewScaling/blob/main/ViewScaling/ScalingView.swift)

Comment: @HangarRash Fixed. Thanks for pointing this out. [GitHub](https://github.com/ll3Ynxnj/Sample-Swift-ViewScaling/blob/main/ViewScaling/ViewController.swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that every time you execute `subview.transform`, the `layoutSubviews` function also gets called, and the subview frame changes too. Without animation or delay, it actually does transform then back to the original frame. You can put some `animate` to check:

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    self.subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
}
```

To avoid it, you have to move the setup size and frame to `init` so it will get called once. Then transform from outside, maybe from `ViewController`:

```swift
class ScalingView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        ...
        let subviewSize = 100
        subview.frame.size = CGSize(width: subviewSize, height: subviewSize)
        subview.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY)
    }

    func scaleSubView(_ scale: CGFloat = 1.5) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    scalingView.scaleSubView()
}
```

Notice: @matt and @HangarRash advice is helpful, you should follow it.

Comment: I have updated the transform in the View's initialization and achieved the desired drawing result. It was enlightening to learn that updating the transform in viewWillAppear might lead to issues. Thank you so much for your guidance.
[GitHub](https://github.com/ll3Ynxnj/Sample-Swift-ViewScaling/blob/main/ViewScaling/ScalingView.swift)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your advice a bit. I guess I misunderstood your advice a bit: you don't have a problem with performing view transforms within layoutSubviews, but with setting up frames and transforms at the same time within layoutSubviews.

Comment: I mean setting up the view frame should be done once time and `layoutSubviews` gets called multiple times during the view life circle. If you're putting `scalingView` in `viewWillAppear`, it will be: `viewWillAppear -> layoutSubViews -> transform -> layoutSubViews`. It gets called twice in a short time, instead of one. I'm pointing out why `transform` does not work as expected.

Comment: The entire flow is: on the first `layoutSubviews`, `transform` gets called, and the view transform is exactly as input, i.e: (scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5). Then the second `layoutSubviews`, reset the view frame to original, and the transform is still (scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5). It should be .identity. You must break the flow somehow and I suggest putting the frame setup in init so it will not be reset again during transforming.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Your explanation has given me something to verify. Please give me some time.

Comment: I am a bit perplexed by the fact that changing **transform** property of sub views triggers the parent view's **layoutSubviews**. I have always understood **layoutSubviews** to be called when the shape of a view changes, so I have always set **frame** property of sub views within **layoutSubviews**. When I want to change **transform** property of a sub views, where is the best place to set **frame** property of sub views?

Maybe they shouldn't be used together at the same time?

Comment: `layoutSubViews` may be called multiple times such as: after `setNeedsLayout` or `layoutIfNeeded`, etc. From my perspective, `frame` should be set once (in case it doesn't need to change its position), and handle `transform` with its states (scale <-> identity). The purpose is: to avoid conflict, i.e, you have a view that has a width of 100 points, then you scale it down to 0.2, then reset the width to 100 again. So what is the view state now, it has 100 points on width but its transform still scales down to 0.2. This is a conflict. They can be used together, but not in this circumstance.